Corel Draw - Transparency tool keep applying whenever i make a new object
help me, the transparency tool is keep applying whenever i make/create a new object and fill it with color, it applies to when i do a trace bitmap, the object will have a tranparency effect applied to it. How do i turn this setting off?

From what I remember of Corel Draw (haven’t used it in years), you should be able to get rid of this annoyance the following way: Select no object, and remove the transparency just as you would remove it from an object that would be selected. I can’t remember how it’s done, but you probably know what I mean.


Open a new document without anything.
Select the no transparency icon.
A dialog box will pop asking you if you want to apply this setting as default.



To save these settings to any new document, now go to... Tools? (mine is in Spanish) And apply these settings to all new documents. (This is why we made a blank document in the first place)


